# Contar el numero de Hombres y Mujeres en un un rango de fechas en mySQL

Tags: mysql, count

Buen día a todos, tengo el siguiente conflicto.
En mySQL Tengo una tabla `alumnos` con los siguientes campos: `sexo` (aquí registro si son hombres o mujeres) y `Entrada` (aquí registro las fechas).

Necesito contar el numero de hombres y mujeres en un intervalo de fechas.
Ejemplo:

> ¿Cuántos hombres y cuantas mujeres se registraron entre las fechas 2022/10/1 y 2022/10/31?

Tenia las siguientes ideas pero ninguna me funciona:

1.- `where Entrada=? and Entrada=? (select sexo,count(*) from alumnos group by sexo)`

2.- `select sexo,count(*) from alumnos group by sexo where Entrada between ? and ?`

agradecería muchísimo si alguien pudiera asesorarme. gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! una de las dos opciones, es cualquier cosa.. la otra, es lo que queres, pero esta desordenada... entonces cual es la pregunta????

Comment: osea que no me vas ayudar :"c

Comment: @YahirArmandoGonzalezGonzale Ayudá a que los demás te ayuden: ¿cuál es la pregunta? Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si.. por eso mi comentario... si una de las dos, hace lo que vos queres, la probaste? que error te dio? asi te ayudamos tambien a entender los errores y aprendes a corregirlos.. de que te sirve que solo te corrija el query (que como te dije, es correcto, pero esta desordenada?)....